# CLR version issues with Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, graph, json.net, clr

I have a C# solution that utilizes Microsoft Graph v3.31.0.
This library is added to the C# project via nuget and has a dependency to Newtonsoft.Json v6.0.1.

Now I have a CLR solution that maps the functions from the C# solution to a C++ solution.
This works fine.

My issue: In other projects I use the latest version of Newtonsoft.Json v13.
When I update the C# solution to use Newtonsoft.Json v13 the C# functionality works just fine.
However the CLR part does not work anymore, saying it wants v6.0.1.
Checking this up further, this version seems to be hardcoded in the Microsoft.Graph.dll (viewed with a Texteditor).

Is there a possibility to make the CLR/C++ project work with the latest Newtonsoft.Json that is newer than the referenced library from Microsoft.Graph?
Due to security concerns I'm not comfortable using a 7+ year old library.